# C++ type casting pointers to constant variables

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, constants

I'm hoping there's a way to write a single get function for a class with a large number of accessible (but non-editable) data members, of mixed type. Use of a map holding void*-cast copies of the members' addresses will work, as seen in the following code, but as soon as a 'const' is thrown in to the mix to enforce read-only, unsurprisingly C++ barks saying that 'const void*' type cannot be recast in order to appropriately access the data member. The following code works for writing a single get function for a class of mixed data types, but it effectively makes all data members accessed by the get function public (see specifically the `get` function in the `memlist` class).

Bottom line:

Is there a way to make a pointer type-castable while retaining read-only at the actual memory location? Or more fundamentally, can one define a type cast-able pointer to a constant variable? E.g., it seems to me that `const type *var` defines a read-only/non-castable address to a read-only variable, whereas I am trying to find something (that hasn't worked for me as of yet) more like `type * const var`, though I haven't been able to find any documentation on this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class A{
public:
    A(int a, double b): a(a), b(b) {};
private:
    int a;
    double b;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A& rhs);
};

class memlist{
public:
    memlist(int param1, double param2)
    {
        myint = new int(param1);
        mydouble = new double(param2);
        myclass = new A(param1,param2);

        getMap["myint"] = myint;
        getMap["mydouble"] = mydouble;
        getMap["myclass"] = myclass;
    }
    ~memlist()
    {
        delete myint;
        delete mydouble;
        delete myclass;
    }
    void* get(std::string param) {return getMap[param];};
private:
    int *myint;
    double *mydouble;
    A *myclass;

    std::map<std::string,void*> getMap;
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, A& rhs){
    os << rhs.a << std::endl << rhs.b;
    return os;
};

int main(){
    int myint = 5;
    double mydbl = 3.14159263;
    memlist mymem(myint,mydbl);

    std::cout << *(int*)mymem.get("myint") << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(double*)mymem.get("mydouble") << std::endl;
    std::cout << *(A*)mymem.get("myclass") << std::endl;
    *(int*)mymem.get("myint") = 10;
    std::cout << *(int*)mymem.get("myint") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
5
3.14159
5
3.14159
10
```

Comment: I feel sorry for the programmer who has to maintain this code.  C++ has `std::any` for things like this.

Comment: [std::any usage](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af4a1032226f6d60)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Thankfully this is just me playing with pointers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code shown is very, shall we say, ill-designed.

`void*` is as close to destroying the type system as it gets in C++. As mentioned in the comments, `std::any` is a better solution to this.

That said, I took it as a challenge to implement what you have illustrated in the question in a type-safe manner. It was overkill, to say the least.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<typename>
struct is_str_literal : false_type {};

template<size_t N>
struct is_str_literal<const char[N]> : true_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_str_literal<T&> : is_str_literal<T> {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_str_literal_v = is_str_literal<T>::value;

constexpr bool samestr(const char* arr1, const char* arr2, size_t n)
{
    return n == 0 ? arr1[0] == arr2[0] :
                    (arr1[n] == arr2[n]) && samestr(arr1, arr2, n - 1);
}

template<size_t N1, size_t N2>
constexpr bool samestr(const char (&arr1)[N1], const char (&arr2)[N2])
{
    return N1 == N2 ? samestr(arr1, arr2, N1 - 1) : false;
}

constexpr char myint[] = "myint";
constexpr char mydouble[] = "mydouble";
constexpr char myclass[] = "myclass";

struct S
{
    template<const auto& name>
    const auto& get()
    {
        static_assert(is_str_literal_v<decltype(name)>, "usage: get<var name>()");
        if constexpr(samestr(name, ::myint))
            return myint;
        if constexpr(samestr(name, ::mydouble))
            return mydouble;
        if constexpr(samestr(name, ::myclass))
            return myclass;
    }

    int myint;
    double mydouble;
    char myclass;
};

int main()
{
    S s;
    s.myint = 42;
    s.mydouble = 10.0;
    s.myclass = 'c';
    cout << s.get<myint>() << endl;
    cout << s.get<mydouble>() << endl;
    cout << s.get<myclass>() << endl;
}
```

[Live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f9a4829d0c3bf0d)

This uses C++17.

Answer (score 0):

After some further poking around, I have to respectfully disagree with the previous assessments in the comments and answers... I have, since posting this question, come across many functions *in the standard C library* where void * types are readily used (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), not to mention it being the return type of malloc (probably the most widely-used function in C/C++?) which relies on programmer type-casting. Also, to the best of my knowledge, std::any is a new c++17 class, so how might you have answered this question 6 months ago?